# How do I get the stylus working on a Lenovo X220 Tablet?

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, tablet, stylus

I have just got a Lenovo X220 Tablet and I would like to have a dual boot with Ubuntu. I installed it successfully but after installing Inkscape and Xournal I realized that the stylus doesn't work (it seems that it is not recognized).

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it in a Lenovo tablet?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This may or may not be the same problem, but here's an answer I found recently for an X200 tablet with Ubuntu 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551324/thinkpad-x201-tablet-touchscreen-not-recognized/568843#568843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found in a previous question an answer directing to the website --> http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Wacom_Serial_Tablet_PC_Stylus

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, my X220 would not respond to the stylus (but it would to my finger) until I rotated the screen using the display settings. Once rotated to portrait mode, the stylus responded but not correctly, rather sending the mouse off as if the mouse's domain was still in landscape. Upon returning to landscape orientation, the stylus worked as it was supposed to.  I have no explanation why this happened, but I rebooted the tablet multiple times before changing the orientation and always to no avail.

Using Oneiric as of December 30 2011, Fresh install, fully updated, no Xorg.conf file, just the stock software bundle as-is (new computer, fresh install).