# Thinkpad x201 tablet touchscreen not recognized

Tags: thinkpad, tablet

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

gives me nothing, however, on Windows7 touch-screen and stylus works fine. How to fix this on ubuntu 14.10 up to date

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xinput/+bug/1275416 has a lot of hints. Seems that the touchscreen support for your laptop is quite buggy...

Answer (score 3):

I just encoutered this problem on an X200 tablet. With some digging around I found the solution/workaround on this launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887

The most concise answer on there is comment #8: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887/comments/8

I'll quote it here:

> linuxwacom maintainer here --
>
> It looks like the problem is that the udev rules are being placed in a subdirectory for some reason. Placing them within the rules directory itself (as Debian does) and then rebooting seems to work fine:

```
# mv /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/wacom.rules /tmp/69-wacom.rules
# rmdir /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
# mv /tmp/69-wacom.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/
```

Like they say, after a reboot the wacom device worked for me.